# How does Venturi effect work in this case?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

I'm not a physicist or a student. I just wanted to understand how the Venturi effect works in this case.

I understand that the Venturi effect says that when a fluid flows through a constricted area, the pressure in the constricted area is lower than other areas of a pipe.

But let's imagine a straight glass pipe with no constricted areas into which we pass a fluid, it seems like we can overwhelm a pipe by passing, a huge amount of fluid really fast, and it will break, however, if the pipe was wider, it wouldn't break. Doesn't this contradict the Venturi effect? Or am I not understanding something? Why did the narrow glass pipe break, but the wide one didn't? To me it seems that the narrow one broke because there was a lot more pressure, than in the wide one.

The same example can be given about the human nose. Why is it that when my nasal passages get narrow from partial congestion, I feel more pressure in my nose when breathing in, compared to when I spray a decongestant into my nose and my nasal passages get opened up? I'm not talking about pressure from nasal structures pressing one each other, I'm talking about breathing, and feeling that the air is able to barely pass through a narrow passage to the point that you feel it pressuring your nasal passages. Why do I feel more air pressure in narrow nasal passages compared to wide ones?

Maybe what I am talking about isn't pressure, but wall shear stress? Are they different in a Venturi tube? It seems like wall shear stress is higher in a constricted area. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think we feel greater air pressure in our noses when our nostrils are constricted.

Comment: @electronpusher I have an endoscope which I can use to look into my nose. When the nasal passage is very narrow, the septum starts fluctuating a little bit when I breathe in, it's because the air stream pushes nasal structures apart to make way for itself. However my septum doesn't fluctuate when I spray a decongestant and my airway is free. Doesn't this mean that there's more pressure? Or whatever it's called, wall shear stress. Is there a difference between pressure and wall shear stress?